# Root path for Backbone urls (Backbone.js depoyed in suburi)

Tags: url, backbone.js, deployment

I have my Rails and Backbone.js application deployed to a suburi. What is the best way to prepend all request with the suburi?

Example: application is deployed to `www.example.com/app`. I have a resource `users` and I'd like backbone to call `www.example.com/app/users` instead of the default `www.example.com/users`.

I'm setting a `ROOT_URI` variable on the server side and I'm going to use it in the backbone app. The simple way is to add it to all urls in models and collections, but it's tedious and error prone. What should I do? Override `Backbone.sync`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass URL on your Fetch call

**Example**

```
model.fetch({
            url: yourServiceURL,
            success: function (response, xhr)
            {
                //console.log("Successfully Fetched...");

            },
            error: function()
            {
                //console.log("Error Occurred...");

            }
        });
```

in this way you don't have to define url in your model and collections

**EDIT**
what i understand from your comment. you can do something like this

```
yourModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        url:function() {
          return yourGlobalVarForRootURI+"/staticLogicalPathForEachModel";
        },
        parse: function (response) {

            return response;
        }

 });
```

in this way you can give `yourGlobalVarForRootURI` variable in all of your models/collections and you can change this global variable so it will be changed in all models/collection. I hope it will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks, but this way I have to care about the root URL even more: I have to remember about it every time I do fetch or save instead of overriding it once per model/collection. What I'd like to do is set the root path once per app so that it's automatically used by all models and collections.

Comment: i have edited my answer. please check the Edit section and do let me know if i still don't get your point :)

Comment: Finally I did something similar to what you suggested. I set an application suburi as a global variable and prepend all the URLs in backbone using a helper function.